Meaning of "literary and argumentative artisans and repulsive coquetry with them"
The following text is from a letter written by Mikhail Bakunin (1814-1876). I don't know exactly when it was translated into English, but I'm quoting directly from a book published in 1917 or 1918. I'm trying to understand the part I've emphasized by making it bold.

The Germans, artisans, Bornstedt, Marx and Engels—and, above all, Marx—are here, doing their ordinary mischief. Vanity, spite, gossip, theoretical overbearingness and practical pusillanimity—reflections on life, action and simplicity, and complete absence of life, action and simplicity—literary and argumentative artisans and repulsive coquetry with them: 'Feuerbach is a bourgeois,' and the word 'bourgeois' grown into an epithet and repeated ad nauseum, but all of them themselves from head to foot, through and through, provincial bourgeois. With one word, lying and stupidity, stupidity and lying. In this society there is no possibility of drawing a free, full breath. I hold myself aloof from them, and have declared quite decidedly that I will not join their communistic union of artisans, and will have nothing to do with it.

What does "them" in "with them" refer to? It's not clear at all. Perhaps highly literary language is being used.
Does it simply mean that the people mentioned are "literary and argumentative artisans" who do repulsive flirtations?

The translation is a bit stiff. I'd go with "their coquettishness" or "their coyness," though I judge the comment as a bit sexist (See "girly-men.") As for argumentative artisans, the writer disagrees with their style and is being bitchy about their bitchiness, so they are the ones being argumentative. Just sayin'.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not about English language usage, it's about understanding the meaning of a short passage within the translation of a quite old piece of literature. It would be on-topic on our sibling site Literature Stack Exchange but it's off-topic here.

No idea why the post got locked. You've got the wrong meaning of coquetry. Here it refers to a weak constitution, a lack of discipline, and a defective way of thinking. The paragraph reads as a litany of reasons supporting the critic's position they are hypocrites and pretenders. The bolded text has parallel semantics to the preceding sentences - contrasting the all-to-righteous noise with the seedy reality.
And calling them names while complaining they called others names is a bit rich, and possibly intentional.

I locked it because people were using the comment box for their answers.

With "flirtation", I meant almost the same thing as you described. Thanks for your post. I voted it up. But I think it doesn't answer the question I asked, at least explicitly.
